# Program is written but cant get it to concatenate

Tags: python-3.x

This program takes 4 points on a graph and puts them into a Lagrange polynomial. I got my terms to output correctly but I need to concatenate the 4 terms into 1 line of code. No matter where I seem to try to concatenate, it keeps messing up the loops and therefore messing up my terms. I'm sure there is an easier way to do this, but I have to use strings and concatenation for my assignment. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
import string
from math import *

def main():
    n=4
    abscissa=[-5,-2,3,7]
    ordinate=[4,-6,8,1]

    for j in range(n):
        LP=str(ordinate[j])
        denom="1"
        for k in range(n):
            if k!=j:
                denom= denom+"*("+str(abscissa[j])+"-"+str(abscissa[k])+")"
                LP=LP+"*(x-"+str(abscissa[k])+")"
        LP=LP+'/'+denom
        print(LP)

main()
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: 4*(x--2)*(x-3)*(x-7)/1*(-5--2)*(-5-3)*(-5-7) + -6*(x--5)*(x-3)*(x-7)/1*(-2--5)*(-2-3)*(-2-7) + 8*(x--5)*(x--2)*(x-7)/1*(3--5)*(3--2)*(3-7) + 1*(x--5)*(x--2)*(x-3)/1*(7--5)*(7--2)*(7-3)

Comment: I have it so the terms list on 4 different lines of code, but I need them to be concatenated onto 1 line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect the terms, and join them:

```
import string
from math import *

def main():
    n=4
    abscissa=[-5,-2,3,7]
    ordinate=[4,-6,8,1]
    result = ''
    for j,y in enumerate(ordinate):
        if j!=0:
            result += '+'
        LP=str(y)
        denom="1"
        for k,x in enumerate(abscissa):
            if k!=j:
                denom += '*({}-{})'.format(abscissa[j],x)
                LP += '*(x-{})'.format(x)
        LP += '/' + denom
        result += LP
    print(result)
main()
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Unfortunately, I don't think it will work for this assignment as its a class of beginner python programmers (we havent even went over the format,result, and join functions) and the assignment calls for the use of concatenated strings.

Comment: OK, removed the join and did more concatenation.